# Preventing observable sharing for certain subtrees in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, data-reify

I have an EDSL which offers list-like combinators for arrays (`map`, `zipWith`, etc..)

Some combinators require certain inputs to be random access. E.g. the data array of `Gather` picking the elements from data array at the indices specified by the other:

```
Gather (Manifest [10,11,12]) (Manifest [2,0,0,1,2]) = [12,10,10,11,12]
```

The language makes use of `data-reify` package for recovering sharing. The problem is that sometimes the same subtree contains both nodes that need to provide random access and those that can be computed sequentially. Having them shared breaks the subsequent evaluator.

For example in the tree below I would like for `[1,2,3]` to keep being shared, but the `Manifests` wrapping them to be different nodes in the recovered graph:

```
     [1, 2, 3]
     /       \
 Manifest Manifest
    |        |
    |     Map (+1)
    \     /
    Gather
```

A more complex example may include a number of shared nodes all of which should become distinct (even though `Map (+1) (Manifest [1,2,3])` could be shared.

```
     [1, 2, 3]
     /       \
 Manifest Manifest
    |        |
 Map (+1)  Map (+1)
    |       /|
 Map (*2)  / |
    \     /  |
    Gather   |
        \    |
        ZipWith (+)
```

Even if I find a solution for the simple case (`Gather` references `Manifest` directly), it will already cover most of the use cases.

Any pointers are welcome!

Below is a simple mock-up of the language.

```
module NoSharing where

data AST = Manifest [Int]
         | Map (Int -> Int) AST
         | ZipWith (Int -> Int -> Int) AST AST
         | Gather AST  -- ^ Data
                  AST  -- ^ Indices

complex = ZipWith (+) gathered indexes
  where
    gathered = Gather (Map (*2) indexes) indexes
    indexes  = Map (+1) $ Manifest [1,2,3]


simple = Gather dat indexes
  where
    dat     = Manifest [1,2,3]
    indexes = Map (+1) dat
```

Comment: Can you identify the things that shouldn't be shared by constructor, e.g. all `Manifest`s shouldn't shared?

Comment: Anything relying on observable sharing is bound to be fragile, because Haskell doesn't have observable sharing.  Some implementations allow you recover some of the sharing through dirty tricks.  If you want it to be reliable, you need to make the sharing explicit in the DSL.

Comment: @augustss Observable sharing may produce false negatives, not false positives, so it won't break anything. The program will just run slower. It seemed like the easiest thing to implement. I may still be able to recover implicit sharing the pure way, since the terms can be compared structurally.

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do this is to manually eliminate the sharing before you call `data-reify`. For example, this function should hopefully unshare a top-level `Manifest` constructor, but leave its argument shared:

```
rebuildManifest :: AST -> AST
rebuildManifest (Manifest xs) = Manifest xs
rebuildManifest t = t
```

Now to unshare any `Manifest` under a `Gather`, you could do the same thing recursively, taking care to reuse the original when appropriate

```
rebuildAllManifestsUnderGather :: AST -> (AST, Bool)

rebuildAllManifestsUnderGather t@(Map f t') =
    let (newt', reuse) = rebuildAllManifestsUnderGather t'
    in if reuse then (t, True) else (Map f newt', False)

rebuildAllManifestsUnderGather t@(ZipWith f t1 t2) =
    let (newt1, reuse1) = rebuildAllManifestsUnderGather t1
        (newt2, reuse2) = rebuildAllManifestsUnderGather t2
    in if reuse1 && reuse2 then (t, True) else (ZipWith f newt1 newt2, False)

rebuildAllManifestsUnderGather t@(Gather t1 t2) =
    let (newt1, reuse1) = rebuildManifest $ rebuildAllManifestsUnderGather t1
        (newt2, reuse2) = rebuildManifest $ rebuildAllManifestsUnderGather t2
    in if reuse1 && reuse2 then (t, True) else (Gather newt1 newt2, False)

    where rebuildManifest (Manifest xs, _) = (Manifest xs, False)
          rebuildManifest (t, reuse) = (t, reuse)

rebuildAllManifestsUnderGather t@(Manifest xs) = (t, True)
```

However, **be warned**: observable sharing is not guaranteed and might be unreliable in both directions. The GHC optimiser could quite legally "re-share" the attempts to unshare `Manifest` above. I don't know what it would do in practice.

Also this solution is quite complex, so given the fragility, it might be better to have an explicit unsharing pass *after* calling `data-reify`.

Comment: Ganesh, thanks for your code. I haven't tried it either, but it seems to me that GHC could easily do `rebuildManifest t@(Manifest xs) = t` to avoid reconstructing the term. While `data-reify` may indeed produce false negatives, it won't produce false positives, so it won't break anything. However, if I don't unshare `Manifest`s, things will break badly.

Comment: I recall reading that GHC *never* shared things that aren't shared at source level because of an explicit choice to avoid it to avoid problems. Is that no longer the case?

Comment: @codeshot no idea. If you can find a reference one of us could update the answer.